# Symfony 2 : Authentication exception occurred

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony site which works and was developped for version 2.0.9. I tried to upgrade to the latest version (2.4.2) but now each time I try to even access the login page I get a  redirection loop. Here is what the log says:

```
[2014-03-16 12:39:10] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []
```

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Starski\FrontBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:                      sha1
        iterations:                     1
        encode-as-base64:               false
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
         entity:                        { class: Starski\FrontBundle\Entity\User, property: mail }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    index:
        pattern:                        ^/
        form_login:
            login_path:                 /login
            check_path:                 /auth
            default_target_path:        /index
            failure_handler:            starski.security.handler
            success_handler:            starski.security.handler

access_control:
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Anybody know why this could happen ?

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of your `security.yml`? Sounds like there's a problem with the firewall configurations.

Comment: You'll find lots of informations in the [UPGRADE-2.1.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md).

Comment: I've added the contents of my security.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following:

1. Your login_path is **behind** your firewall. This will never authenticate like this.
   Add this to your access control: 
   `- { path: ^(.*)/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`
2. `login_path`, `check_path` and `default_target_path` should be properly defined route names, not absolute urls.
3. You have a provider defined ('main') which is never in use. 
   Try adding `provider: main` to your form login authentication method.

Things to read:  
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#the-login-form-and-process